# Apache Storm using 100% CPU usage

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am using `storm-core-0.9.0.1` with single local cluster. After starting the storm, CPU usage is constantly `maintaining around 100%` even though it is in idle state. After a long research I found for local cluster, `storm uses LMAX Disruptor` ([reference](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/06/21/understanding-storm-internal-message-buffers/)) which internally uses BlockingWaitStrategy. In that class there is line

`final long availableSequence = _barrier.waitFor(nextSequence, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);`

which makes the storm to use 100% of CPU. And also there is a open bug regarding this issue in this [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-503). **Is there is any solution or any fix available?**

I tried to upgrade `disruptor-2.10.1 jar to disruptor-3.2.1` for Storm but it causes some other issue while start up.

And also I tried by changing the wait strategy (topology.disruptor.wait.strategy) to `SleepingWaitStrategy` in default.yaml which is available in the storm-core-0.9.0.1.jar still the CPU usage is around 100%. In production it is hard to leave the CPU usage of 100%. Any solution?

Comment: put sleep(miliseconds) in nextTuple() method of Spout. keep miliseconds optimum for topology.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. **keep miliseconds optimum for topology** I couldn't able to get you. What was the issue and how it will fix if I put sleep? I couldn't able to understand.